# Possible type-traits bug in MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++17, type-traits

A long time ago (January last year) I made a type-agnostic logging system for my game engine. C++17 happened and I was able to replace lots of complicated lambda logic with `if constexpr`, making the whole thing easier to read and generally *better*. Type-checks in the logger are structured as:

```
if constexpr (std::is_[type]<loggableType>{})
{
    // Type-specific text here...
}
```

So I have a big if/else-if/else tower of those, and it should generate correct results for each supported type-trait (std::is_arithmetic, std::is_union, std::is_class, std::is_pointer, std::is_member_function_pointer, and std::is_enum).

What happens is that I get compiler errors as provided enums, unions, structs, and classes funnel towards `std::is_member_function_pointer`. Is this an MSVC bug or am I missing something?

Hopefully this replicates the issue (see older revisions for my source):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename loggableType>
int TraitTest(loggableType dataLogging)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic<loggableType>{})
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_union<loggableType>{})
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_class<loggableType>{})
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_pointer<loggableType>{})
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_member_function_pointer<loggableType>{})
    {
        std::cout << dataLogging;
        return 4;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_enum<loggableType>{})
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class Chicken
{
public:
    void Squawk() { std::cout << "Squawk?"; }
};

int main()
{
    class testClass { };
    testClass tstClass;
    struct testStruct { };
    testStruct tstStruct;
    union testUnion { };
    testUnion tstUnion;
    enum class TEST_ENUM_VALS { VAL_0, VAL_1 };
    Chicken testChicken = Chicken();
    int result0 = TraitTest(tstStruct);
    int result1 = TraitTest(tstClass);
    int result2 = TraitTest(tstUnion);
    int result3 = TraitTest(TEST_ENUM_VALS::VAL_0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide *just* a [mcve] to replicate the issue, instead of snippets from your engine we can't compile by ourselves?

Comment: Yup!
See the newest edit :)

Comment: Not quite. For one thing `enumData` is undefined. For another, the actual logging to `std::cout` code is not important if you ask about a compiler error. But it is getting there.

Comment: Do you know that it is the actual type traits that are misidentified, and not just the compiler being overeager in type checking of not-taken constexpr branches? That would be a bug too IIUC, but a very different kind.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It feels a lot like the latter. I just tested my updated minimal example in a fresh project and everything worked perfectly (e.g. structs/classes returned 2, a union returned 1, and an enum returned 5)...up until I added type-sensitive code to the std::is_member_function_pointer branch (which threw the same errors I was seeing before). How would I work around that?

Comment: @PaulFerris Your best bet is to hide the type-specific stuff (like "get an address representing it") inside a helper template function and hope the compiler doesn't instantiate that. Also, file a bug.

Comment: I actually fixed it by accident just now, by making each `if constexpr` condition a complete exclusive statement (so "if a AND NOT b AND NOT c..." instead of just "if a (implied NOT b, c, etc.)"). I guess that means the compiler is ignoring the "else" part of each else-if-constexpr statement (but type-traits I'm using should be mutually exclusive anyway...)? And yeah, filing a bug would be a good idea :P